# Changing observation values of a column in a dataframe (which follows pattern) for names

Tags: python, pandas, string

I'm working with a dataframe that contains several observations of BMW cars. The thing is that in the model columns I got several models like

```
Model 
320
420
425
335
325
118
Z4
.
.
.
```

I want to change the number to its series, the ones that start by 1 are serie1, if starts with 2 are serie2. I've already checked `str.contains(pat = '1')` but I still don't know how to apply it to the whole column.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Pandas has a [pandas.Series.str.replace](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html) method which can be used for this purpose. You would do something like:

```py
df['Model'].str.replace('^1', 'serie1')
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want to get first character from the model column:

```py
df["Serie"] = "Serie " + df["Model"].str[0]
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
  Model    Serie
0   320  Serie 3
1   420  Serie 4
2   425  Serie 4
3   335  Serie 3
4   325  Serie 3
5   118  Serie 1
6    Z4  Serie Z
```